# Using Keras with ProcessPoolExecutor gives "TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects" when retrieving result() from Futures object

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, concurrent.futures, tf.keras

I am trying to parallelize the k-fold validation example for Boston Housing Prices regression in Francois Chollet's Deep Learning with Python book. This builds a small NN for regression using Keras.  The NN is trained on four different training examples obtained by changing the holdout examples for validation.  These are four independent training runs that should be easy to parallelize, or so I thought.

I am running Python 3.7.3 and fairly recent Keras under Anaconda in a Jupiter notebook.  I decided to try and use the concurrent.futures library for parallelization.

I have looked at other related StackOverflow questions and they don't solve my problem. [Checkpointing keras model: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066635/checkpointing-keras-model-typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects)
[can't pickle _thread.RLock objects using keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421480/cant-pickle-thread-rlock-objects-using-keras)
etc...

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

boston_housing = tf.keras.datasets.boston_housing
models = tf.keras.models
layers = tf.keras.layers

# load data
(train_data, train_targets), (test_data, test_targets) = boston_housing.load_data()

# normalize the features (subtract mean and divide by standard deviation)
mean = train_data.mean(axis=0)
std = train_data.std(axis=0)
train_data -= mean
train_data /= std
test_data -= mean
test_data /= std

# model definition
def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape = (train_data.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    return model

# build and train model on one fold of training/validation split
def build_and_train_model( fold, num_folds = 4, num_epochs = 100 ):
    num_val_samples = len(train_data) // num_folds
    start_idx = fold*num_val_samples
    end_idx = (fold+1)*num_val_samples
    partial_train_data = np.concatenate(
        [train_data[:end_idx], train_data[end_idx:]], axis = 0)
    partial_train_targets = np.concatenate(
        [train_targets[:end_idx], train_targets[end_idx:]], axis = 0)
    model = build_model()
    history = model.fit(partial_train_data, partial_train_targets, epochs=num_epochs, 
                        batch_size=1, verbose=0)
    return (model, history)

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

k = 4
num_epochs = 10
futures = []
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for i in range(k):
        future = executor.submit(build_and_train_model, i, 
                                 num_folds = k, num_epochs = num_epochs )
        futures.append(future)
    models = []
    histories = []
    for future in futures:
        model, history = future.result() 
        models.append(models)
        histories.append(history)
```

```
This is the error message:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 205, in _sendback_result
    exception=exception))
  File "//anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 358, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "//anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-499a12f73b9e> in <module>
     13     histories = []
     14     for future in futures:
---> 15         model, history = future.result()
     16         models.append(models)
     17         histories.append(history)

//anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    433                 raise CancelledError()
    434             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 435                 return self.__get_result()
    436             else:
    437                 raise TimeoutError()

//anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Is there a way to get around this error?  Or is there a different way to achieve what I am trying to do -- namely launch multiple parallel training sessions?

Comment: Hello were you able to find a solution to this issue?